# retrieve topic-word array & document-topic array from lda gensim

Tags: lda, gensim

**Situation:**

I have a numpy term-document matrix 
example: [[0,1,0,0....],....[......0,0,0,0]].

I have plugged in the above matrix to the ldamodel method of the gensim. And it is working fine with the lad method `lda = LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=10)`. 
`corpus` is my term-document matrix mentioned above.
I needed two intermediate matrices( **topic-word array & document-topic array**) for research purpose.

> 1) per document-topic probability matrix (p_d_t)
>
> 2) per topic-word probability matrix (p_w_t)

**Question:**

How to get those array from the gensim `LdaModel()` function.? Kindly help me with getting those matrices.

Comment: If you use lda.print_topics(k) it will print the per word propability, and with vec_lda = lda[document] it wll show you the per topic probability.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1.Per-document topic probability matrix:

Apply a [transformation](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut2.html) to your corpus.

```
docTopicProbMat = lda[corpus]
```

2. Per-topic word probability matrix:

`K = lda.num_topics
topicWordProbMat = lda.print_topics(K)`